# Jest encountered an unexpected token, Unexpected token export

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, babeljs

I've created a Yarn Workspace, it contains of two packages: Client and Service.

When my Component in the Client package imports a module from the Service package, Jest throws the above error.

[image]

Here is how mi `jest.config.js` looks like

```
const rootTestModule = '<rootDir>';

module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
  testMatch: ['**/?(*.)(test).js?(x)'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.jsx?$': `${rootTestModule}/jest/babel-preprocessor.js`,
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.scss$': require.resolve('./style-mock.js'),
  },
  snapshotSerializers: ['jest-emotion'],
  transformIgnorePatterns:['<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!@rppm)'],
};
```

Here is the `babel-preprocessor.js` file

```
const { createTransformer } = require('babel-jest');

const babelConfig = {
  presets: ['@babel/env', '@babel/react'],
  plugins: [
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from',
    '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
    'transform-es2015-modules-commonjs',
  ]
};
```

Here is the package im trying to use

[image]

Comment: Can you please add the package.json of `@rppm/service`?

Comment: ```{
  "name": "@rppm/service",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "fetch-mock": "^9.0.0-beta.2",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1"
  }
}
```